# How to configure datagen connector in confluent control center

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to know the procedure where i can use data gen connector in confluent center such that i can generate random data for test topic.

I tried connecting datagen connector with some settings but it always fails.

Update: I tried connecting my own schema created in topic but its not picking it up  and datagen connector is failing to start.

here is config for datagen connect :

```
{
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "datagen-protobuf-userprofile",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
  "transforms": [
    "SetSchemaMetadata"
  ],
  "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
  "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "value_User_PROFILE",
  "kafka.topic": "User_PROFILE",
  "max.interval": "1000",
  "iterations": "10000000",
  "schema.filename": "value_User_PROFILE",
  "schema.keyfield": "userid",
  "quickstart": "value_User_PROFILE"
}
```

Schema defined in new topic :

```
{
  "doc": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "doc": "The int type is a 32-bit signed integer.",
      "name": "userid",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The string is a unicode character sequence.",
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The string is a unicode character sequence.",
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The string is a unicode character sequence.",
      "name": "countrycode",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "doc": "this si double which store floting value as well",
      "name": "rating",
      "type": "double"
    }
  ],
  "name": "value_User_PROFILE",
  "namespace": "com.mycorp.mynamespace",
  "type": "record"
}
```

Comment: "always fails..." with what error? And do you **need** control center since datagen is not actually installed there, and in the Connect cluster itself?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i have updated question , please help

Comment: you say "failing to start", but show no logs...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps :

1. Place the datagen connector directory in the configured plugin path -- incase of  distributed workers you need to do this for all the workers
2. Restart all workers
3. The connector should appear on the connector list page on control center (hit `connect-ip:8083/connector-plugins` to confirm if connector was loaded correctly)
4. Fill in the connector properties -- you can refer to the following repo for sample config values : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/tree/master/config (You can also upload the properties file on control center)
5. Test and continue , later start the connector

Comment: I want to generate data for my own schema , please let me know how can i do it and for sample config's am able to use datagen connector successfully.

Comment: To create your custom schema you need to remove the `quickstart` config from your properties and add the following config:
`"schema.filename": "/path/to/your_schema.avro"`
`"schema.keyfield": "<field representing the key>"`

The connector uses **Avro Random Generator** so you need to make sure that your schema is compatible with it _your schema looks fine_

This is a sample custom config file:  [https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/blob/master/config/connector_custom.config]